# This regex fails in cucumber but passes in regex tool

Tags: java, regex, cucumber, gherkin

I have a statement

```
Scenario Outline
@Given I have a coupon for "<campaign_name>"

Examples:
|Hotel|
|Movie|
|Shopping|
```

For this statement I have regex as:

```
@Given("^I have a coupon for \\\"([^\\\\\\\"]*)\\\"$")
```

I want to test this statement on popular online regex tool https://regexr.com/
Where it is failing, how come it is passing in Cucumber?
[image]

Also, if I do reverse i.e. a regex passing in tool, then it fails in Cucumber.
[image]

If I use

`@Given("^I have a coupon for [^]*$")` it will fail.

I want to write good, optimum, readable, short regex, for that I am dependent on tool. Please check, what am I doing wrong?

**Update: using quotes not skipping them**

It also give error
[image]

Comment: You don't need to unnecessarily escape a doublequote and can simply write your regex like this `^I have a coupon for "([^"]*)"$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QN6sIk/1)

Comment: I have tried , it is giving error. See screenshot attached.

Comment: You need to escape `"` as `\"` for Java at least. Use this escaped version of string `"^I have a coupon for \"([^\"]*)\"$"`

Comment: `"` is not a special regex metacharacter, you should not escape it.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi It worked. [at]Wiktor Got it.